# Подчеркивание ссылок

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как убрать подчеркивание ссылок (интересуют все способы).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a { text-decoration: none }` - самый нормальный способ

Answer (score 6):

```
css:
a {
    text-decoration:none
}
```

*И перед тем как задавать вопрос - соизвольте воспользоватся гуглом...*

Answer (score 1):

если в ссылке есть изображение то:

```
img{
border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: а еще лучше:<br>
`img {
   border:none;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще: `a{text-decoration:none!important}`

Comment: а причем тут модификатор приоритетности?

Answer (score 1):

> интересуют все способы

```
a{
    text-decoration: none !important; /*стандарт*/
    border-bottom: none !important; /*а вдруг кто-то так подчеркивает*/
    background-image: none !important; /*возможно, даже картинкой*/
}
```

Пока идеи закончились. У кого еще что-то есть? =)

Comment: я тоже этого непонимаю :D<br>
ТС просто спросил как убрать подчеркивание а не как полезно в ИЕ ФФ и т.д :D

Answer (score 0):

А для ссылок картинок в FF полезно

```
a img { border: none; }
```